# Am I using navigationOptions class variable the right way with React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation and I have a TabNavigator nested inside another TabNavigator. 
As I defined the class Variable navigationOptions in the ReviewScreen and added the right property in the header, I ended up with an Invariant Voliation error . However, from all the documentations I have read about react-navigation, it seems the my navigationOptions is done the appropriate way.

Below is my App.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
      main: {
        screen: TabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: { screen: StackNavigator({
            review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
            Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
          })}
        })
      }
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </View>
    );
   }
}
```

[image]

Here is my ReviewScreen component, with the navigationOptions class variable included .

```
 class ReviewScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Review Jobs',
   header: ({ navigate }) => {
     return {
       right: (
         <Button
           title="Settings"
           onPress={() => navigate('settings')}
           backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
           color="rgba(0, 122, 255, 1)"
         />
       )
     };
   }
 }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text> ReviewScreen </Text>
        <Text> ReviewScreen </Text>
        <Text> ReviewScreen </Text>
        <Text> ReviewScreen </Text>
        <Text> ReviewScreen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the latest [`docs`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#header), the header is

> **React Element** or a **function** that given **HeaderProps** returns a **React Element**.

Since your header is a function that returns an `Object` and not a `React.Element`, therefore it throws out the *Objects are not a valid React.Child* error.

Alternatively what you can do is move your `headerRight` to the parent `navigationOptions` as

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Review Jobs',
        headerRight: (
            <Button
                title="Settings"
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}
                backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                color="rgba(0, 122, 255, 1)"
            />
        )
    })
```